# PGFplots 3D: Axis labels are placed "in the middle" of axis instead at the tip

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I would like to use the "center"-style for axis and place the label of the axis near the arrow tip. It works in 2D but in 3D the labels for the x and y axis are placed at very weird places. See the picture for an example. And it is not the PGFplot bug prior to version 1.8, because I have 1.11. My code is

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.11,%
    axis lines=center,%
    tick align=outside,%
    xlabel style={anchor=south west},%
    ylabel style={anchor=south west},%
    zlabel style={anchor=south west},%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis} [
  name=A,
  xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}
]
\addplot+ coordinates { (1,1) (2,2) };
\end{axis}

\begin{axis} [
  at={(A.south)},
  anchor=north,
  yshift=-1cm,
  xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$} ]
\addplot3+ coordinates { (1,1,1) (2,2,2) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What do I do wrong?

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 1):

This is (most probably) because of a "race condition". That means it is a question of what is executed when. So you will get the desired output if you either put your key-values directly to the corresponding `axis` options or put them in `every axis/.append style` in the `\pgfplotsset`.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use `compat' level 1.8 or higher
        compat=1.8,
        % just put all the options in here and it will work as expected
        every axis/.append style={
            axis lines=center,
            xlabel style={anchor=south west},
            ylabel style={anchor=south west},
            zlabel style={anchor=south west},
            tick align=outside,
        },
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [
            name=A,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
        ]
            \addplot+ coordinates { (1,1) (2,2) };
        \end{axis}

        \begin{axis} [
            at={(A.south)},
            anchor=north,
            yshift=-1cm,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            zlabel={$z$},
%            % -----------------------------------
%            % putting the options directly here
%            % would (also) lead to the expected
%            % result
%            axis lines=center,
%            xlabel style={anchor=south west},
%            ylabel style={anchor=south west},
%            zlabel style={anchor=south west},
%            tick align=outside,
%            % -----------------------------------
        ]
            \addplot3+ coordinates { (1,1,1) (2,2,2) };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]