# pgfplots: 2D contour plot of 3D function: placement of axes labels

Tags: pgfplots, 3d, axis

I'm using pgfplots `\addplot3` to plot contour plots of two-variable functions, as seen in the (x,y) plane (using `view={0}{90}`). However the default placement of the axes labels is odd (I suspect, because of how they are in 3D).

I would like to have the x on the right of the x-axis arrow, and the y above the y-axis arrow. I have followed this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214829/pgfplots-3d-axis-labels-are-placed-in-the-middle-of-axis-instead-at-the-tip), but changing the anchor in `xlabel style` does not seem to change anything on the graph.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
        % use `compat' level 1.8 or higher
        compat=1.8,
        % just put all the options in here and it will work as expected
        every axis/.append style={
            axis lines=center,
            xlabel style={anchor=south west},
            ylabel style={anchor=south west},
            zlabel style={anchor=south west},
            tick align=outside,
        },
    }
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.85,font=\large]
 
 \begin{axis}[ ,
    axis lines=center,
    view={0}{90},
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,     
    ]
 \addplot3 [
    contour gnuplot={levels={0.5,2}},
    domain=0:2,y domain=0:2
 ] {2*x*y };
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that defining the axis label style in `\pgfplotset` does not passed the style properties to Gnuplot. Therefore, you have to define it in the axis environment. You can also control the position of labels with:

`x label style={at={(axis description cs:1.1,0.0)},anchor=center},`

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
        % use `compat' level 1.8 or higher
        compat=1.8,
    }
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.85,font=\large]
 
 \begin{axis}[ ,
    axis lines=center,
    view={0}{90},
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
%    x label style={anchor=south west},
%    y label style={anchor=south west},
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:1.1,0.0)},anchor=center},
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.0,1.1)},anchor=center},
    ]
 \addplot3 [
    contour gnuplot={levels={0.5,2}},
    domain=0:2,y domain=0:2
 ] {2*x*y};
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

P.S: Vladimir has been faster than me ...:)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the location of the axis labels within the axis environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    % use `compat' level 1.8 or higher
    compat=1.8,
    % just put all the options in here and it will work as expected
    every axis/.append style={
        axis lines=center,
        tick align=outside,
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.85,font=\large]
 
 \begin{axis}[ ,
    axis lines=center,
    view={0}{90},
    xlabel style={right, yshift=5pt},
    ylabel style={above, xshift=5pt},
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    domain=0:2,y domain=0:2,     
    ]
 \addplot3 [
    contour gnuplot={levels={0.5,2}},
    samples=50,
 ] {2*x*y };
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

The `xshift` and `yshift` parameters can be omitted.